# MongoDB replica set of 2 nodes + arbiter in another machine, possible to figure something out?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am about to release a MongoDB-backed app in production and I need a backup DB instance to takeover if the primary fails, I would like to minimize the costs of having to maintain 3 different nodes for a MongoDB Replica set.

I have read it's possible to have a combination of 1Primary + 1Secondary + 1arbiter, and that the arbiter is cheap and could totally be put together any app server. What actually happens if the arbiter node fails ?

I also have

- an autoscaling group for my production applications (rails),
- A "Dev server" which also has several Rails applications, along with a MongoDB server on the same server (only acting as a DB for those specific dev environments)

and I was wondering if it would be possible / not too much of a hassle to put the arbiter somewhere in those guys.

The problems

- with the autoscaling group : every node in there is expected to die at some point or another, and the number of nodes can vary between 1 and, say, 10 (but it is supposed to remain mostly at 1 instances)
- With the dev server : it kinda feels bad to have hardware that shares functionalities for dev/production environments, but then if we're just talking about an arbiter, could that be a solution ? ALso that would mean I have 2 MongoDB server running on the same machine : one full DB for Dev environments, and the production arbiter. Is that doable ? A good alternative ?

The savings would be then the cost of one cheap ec2 (64€/year). Is it possible/worth it ?

Comment: Well, I'll not recommend to have a MongoDB node installed in autoscaling group. As you said, nodes can vary between 1 and 10, this will confuse replicate and will end up in election cycle. In other words, better to have a dedicated instance.

Comment: Hey, I just realized I also have an EC2 machine that I normally use only for development. Could that be a nice alternative in the meantime ? (I edited my post)

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep it up. You can make it arbiter.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep it up" ? What happens if the arbiter node fails ? I was hoping with this setup to achieve resilience in case one of the node fails for any reason.

Comment: I meant you keep it running. If arbiter fails for time being, nothing will happen. However if your primary fails, it's crucial in election of new primary.